# Does $lastBlog = new WP_Query('type=post&posts_per_page=1'); act like an Argument?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have inserted the folllowing code into my index.php file, in order to generate my Blog Loop on my Homepage:

```
<?php   
if ( have_posts() ):                        
    while( have_posts() ): the_post();      
?>
<?php 
    endwhile;
endif;              
?>
```

I have read the WordPress Codex and can see that the below code has been used regularly, instead of my above code.  Referring to my Comments, within the below code, is my understanding accurate and correct?

```
<?php       
    $lastBlog = new WP_Query('type=post&posts_per_page=1'); //This acts like an Argument with an Array.

    if ( $lastBlog->have_posts() ): //The $lastBlog, here, calls/considers the above Argument?
        while( $lastBlog->have_posts() ): $lastBlog->the_post(); 
?>
<?php 
        endwhile;
    endif;              
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) returns an object based on the parameters you feed it. `$lastBlog` is the variable that object is stored in, and something like `$lastBlog->have_posts()` is a method of the WP_Query class. So no, it's not an "argument" in the coding sense.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Would I be right in saying then that the WP_Query returns an object (the object, in this case, being the Blog Posts), where the object returned will be based on the parameters (in this case, 'type=post&posts_per_page=1')?  With that in mind, would my second coding above, with the WP_Query, be redundant if I had no parameters set and thus the 1st coding would suffice?

Comment: No, this is not redundant and actually does two separate things. The first bit of code looks at the main query which is stored in `global $post`, which will be whatever your current request is to Wordpress (single post, page, archive, etc.). The second bit of code is your own query, which will basically just give you the one most recent "post" you have.

Comment: Thank you for your insight Spartacus.  You have been helpful!